# Dialogflow CX $param not showing in agent text

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am getting into CX and have a simple agent going but I cannot get the agent to respond with my filled parameter.

I have a page that asks for @DrinkFrequency and @DrinkChoice, I see both get filled correctly when I test the agent and `$page.params.status = FINAL` takes me to my next page that says

```
So you drink $session.params.DrinkFrequency and prefer to drink $session.params.DrinkChoice
```

But the agent says exactly that, it does not replace `$session.params.DrinkFrequency` or `$session.params.DrinkChoice` with the values the user gave. I know it must be a simple issue but I have tried to write `$session.params.DrinkFrequency` in a few different ways and I looked at the existing tutorial bots and they also have it with just the `$` sign. Am I not saving the user given value?

The page that gets the values has the two parameters and they ask for the value in their "Initial prompt fulfillment" field.

[image: Screen of the page asking for the values with one selected]

Answer (score 2):

You're referring to the entity type, while the display name is the name of your parameter.

If you replace $session.params.DrinkFrequency with $session.params.frequency and $session.params.DrinkChoice with $session.params.preference it should work.